# Maclaurin Series approximation for square root of e

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm looking into how someone would go about this. Can it only be done in the Taylor series explicit form?

Would you make x = 1/2 and go from there?

Comment: Exactly!!!!!!!!

Comment: Or $(1+{1 \over 2n})^n$ for large $n$ :-).

Answer (score 3):

Yes:
$$\sqrt e=e^{1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1/2)^n}{n!}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{48}+\frac{1}{384}+\frac{1}{3840}+\cdots$$